# Existence of paths, homotopy and functions

Tags: algebraic-topology, numerical-methods

Consider the homotopy $h(t,x)=tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)$ in which $f(x)=x^2-5x+6$, and $g(x)=x^2-1$.Show that there exists no path connecting a root of $g$ to a root of $f$.

I assumed there exists a path connecting $1$ and $3$. Therefore there exists a function $\alpha:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha(0)=1$,$\alpha(1)=3$ but I could not proceed.

Comment: I think you mean no paths $\alpha:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $h(t,\alpha(t))=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$?

Comment: The discriminant of the quadratic polynomial $h(t,x)$ is $<0$ for $t\in$ a large subinterval of $[0,1].$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+25+t%5E2-28+t+%2B4%2C+t%3D0+to+1

Answer (score 1):

The homotopy expression can be arranged as
$$
h(t,x)=x^2-5tx+(7t-1)=(x-\tfrac52t)^2-\tfrac14(25t^2-28t+4)\\
=(x-\tfrac52t)^2+\tfrac1{100}(44-(25t-14)^2)
$$
For instance at $t=\frac{14}{25}=0.56$ there are no real roots for $x$.

A larger class of homotopies can be given as
$$
\tilde h(t,x)=h(t,x)+c\,t(1-t)
$$
With $c=-\frac{25}4$ there will always be two distinct real roots, thus there will be homotopy path connecting the root sets at the ends.